# Integral closure/normalization of the cuspidal cubic.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

This is a homework question from my Commutative Algebra class. Please correct me if I'm asking this question in a wrong way.

Let $k$ be any field, and let $A=k[x,y]/(y^2-x^3)$. The question works towards the integral closure of $A$ in three steps.
The first step is to show that the $k$-algebra homomorphism $\phi: A\to k[t]$ sending $x\to t^2$ and $y\to t^3$ is injective and has image $k[t^2,t^3]$, which I have done.
The second step consists of showing that the integral closure of $k[t^2,t^3]$ equals $k[t]$, which I have done by showing that $k[t]$ is contained in $\overline{k[t^2,t^3]}$ and by noting that $k[t]$ is a UFD and thus integrally closed.
The third part is:

> Deduce that the integral closure of $A$ is $A[y/x]$. What monic polynomial with coefficients in $A$ does $y/x$ satisfy?

My own work: We can get the integral closure of $k[t^2,t^3]$ by adjoining the element $t=\frac{t^3}{t^2}$ (in its field of fractions $k(t)$) to $k[t^2,t^3]$. If we would "extend" the domain of the homomorphism $\phi$ to include the field of fractions of $A$ (I'm not sure if I am phrasing this correctly, but I hope it's clear what I mean), such that we can meaningfully speak of $\phi(y/x)=t^3/t^2$, then it would seem to makes sense that we get the integral closure of $A$ by adjoining $y/x$, but here lies exactly my problem: it doesn't make all that much sense to me. The isomorphism is between $k[t^2,t^3]$ and $A$ and not between their respective field of fractions, so how can we "transport" the element $t^3/t^2$ back to $A$ via using $\phi$, and simply conclude that $y/x$ should be adjoined to $A$ to form the integral closure? Is there something I'm missing here?

If anybody can help, it would be greatly appreciated. It's the only question I haven't completed, so even though it's homework, I'm more interested in understanding what's going on here than the actual answer. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess $t^2-x$ will work then.

Comment: An isomorphism of integral domains extends canonically to an isomorphism between their fields of fractions.

Comment: Is this obvious? If so, why?

Comment: It follows from the [universal property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_fractions#Construction) of fields of fractions or, more generally, from the universal property of localisations.

Comment: @B.Pasternak Yes, it is quite obvious: if $f:R\to S$ is an iso of domains, then $a/b\mapsto f(a)/f(b)$ is an iso between their fields of fractions.

Comment: Thank you guys very much. I completely forgot that constructing the field of fractions is just a special example of localisation, and we covered this universal property of localisation you two mention. Now it's indeed very obvious.

Comment: I think you want to map $x \mapsto t^3, \ y \mapsto t^2$.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark You would have been right if it wasn't a type of mine. I've corrected it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $T^2-t^2$ is a monic polynomial which has $t$ as a root, you get that $T^2-x$ is a monic polynomial which has $y/x$ as a root.

Next, the integral closure of $k[t^2,t^3]$ equals $k[t]=k[t^2,t^3][t]$, so the integral closure of $A$ is $A[y/x]$.